# Nicely display floating elements in a responsive web site's overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm developing a responsive e-commerce website. It's fairly tough but I like it :)

For the cart I decided to show the product categories on the shelves and single products in a overlay.

[See here](http://goo.gl/KkZTO)

The problem is that it is almost impossible to style them in a decent way because I don't know how many of them there will be nor how large the viewer's window will be.

What patterns could I use to display this variable length data, and how would I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [jQuery Infinite Carousel](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/) with much success.  It could be a great pattern for your products, being able to display them in an overlay without knowing how many will be available to view.

Coding for the Carousel is fairly straightforward.  Just provide your content in an unordered list and apply the jQuery accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @bpeterson , let me see if I understood well. This Carousel is responsive-ready, so It will adapt to any window size, and it will put my items on a single row, allowing the user to horizontally scroll to see the other products.You are suggesting that showing a single row of products would provide a better ux than having a multi-row table like now, am I correct?

Comment: @Francesco, I was referring to the overlay only really.  I think I'd page the initial table view (with the 5 items in 3 rows) and do a simple jQuery show-hide with some fade-in, fade-out.  It shouldn't be too difficult to build the table in a loop, iterating through the amount of items and when you hit the rowmax (in this case 5) start a new row, when the row count hits 3, end and create a new table.  Then show/hide as I described.

Comment: I tried it. And I've got to say that this is what I was looking for. If it just weren't for the "infinity" thing... :) How could I disable it?  http://jsfiddle.net/2RyuZ/ (ot: Should I make a new question for this?)

Comment: I approved your question, because it's definitely a nice way to solve the problem. New question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495468/remove-infinity-from-infinitecarousel