# Remove Infinity from infiniteCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to resolve a few issues from [infiniteCarousel](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/).
It's great because it's responsive-ready, but there are a couple of problems.

http://jsfiddle.net/2RyuZ

1. I don't really need it to be infinite. I tried removing the infinity thing, but there's something I'm missing.
2. I'd like it focused on the first item. Now it's not. Maybe it's my css fault.

Comment: Could you share the link of where you got that Carousel? (these kind of carousels usually comes with already built-options to do the job, so maybe we find these on your link)

Comment: @ajax333221 Question edited. I edited the script to use divs instead of an unordered list.

Comment: Well, I read it all and failed to find a built-option to remove the infinity. (about starting on the first item do you have "currentPage = 1"?).

Comment: It's just a few lines of code. It shouldn't be hard to find the necessary tweaks (yes, you can ask "then why can't you?").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the same, find it working here: jsfiddle.net/vAwwU